# Need to insert a line at the end of comments section on multiple files?

Tags: batch-file

I need to insert a line (a copyright line) into every c and .h file which is inside a folder. The copyright line needs to be added at the beginning of these files inside the comments section.

These files already have comments in the beginning like

```
/**
Comments1
Comments2
**/
```

I need to add my copyright line at the end of this comment section like this:

```
/**
Comments1
Comments2

**Copyright xyz**
**/
```

How do I do that using batch script or python script?

Comment: Couldn't you add `/* ... */`? It would be much easier, safer, ...

Comment: You can take a look to `fileinput` module that lets process and modify in-place many input files, and the `re` module to insert your copyright when it matches first end of comment.

Answer (score 0):

Simple with a [hybrid JScript/batch utility called REPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053) that performs a regex search and replace on stdin and writes the result to stdout. The utility is pure script that runs on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party executable required. Full documentation is embedded within the utility script.

Assuming REPL.BAT is in your current folder, or better yet, somewhere within your PATH:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "copyright=**Copyright xyz**"
for %%F in (*.h *.c) do (
  type "%%F" | repl "(/\*\*[\w\W]*?)(\*\*/[\w\W]*)" "$1\n%copyright%\n$2" mx >"%%F.new"
  move /y "%%F.new" "%%F" >nul
)
```

Answer (score 0):

batch without tools:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "comend=**/"
set "copyright=**Copyright xyz**"
:tfl
set "tfile=%temp%\%random%"
if exist "%tfile%" goto:tfl

for %%a in (*.c *.h) do (
    set "first=true"
    (for /f "delims=" %%b in ('findstr /n "^" "%%~a"') do (
        set "line=%%b"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:*:=!"
        if "!line!"=="%comend%" if defined first (
            endlocal
            echo(
            echo(%copyright%
            set "first="
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            set "line=!line:*:=!"
        )
        echo(!line!
        endlocal
    ))>"%tfile%"
    move "%tfile%" "%%~a">nul
    echo(%%~a
)
```